# Rails4 InvalidAuthenticityToken random error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I upgraded from Rails 3 to Rails4 and now I am getting InvalidAuthenticityToken error randomly on production only for different actions. I tried to but I can't reproduce it. The params hash contains the authenticity token.

```
Parameters : {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"26+QxdF3aHveYkibn9DJ8Hgz6mUna2v8MOp1bnM78cg=", "session"=>{"email"=>"abc@xyz.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions"}

Parameters : {"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"uafnPb4DjEJuW9YCTP9UB5tXyGlKbZh6uXlc6MVIoG8=", "controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"destroy"}

Parameters : {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Nhp4VNI9XJS7yqGRgGewOJ3ilkZSwMhmceXoOsoL/fw=", "volunteer_record"=>{"activity"=>"OTHER", "note"=>"Tuned the Melody Harp -- a tricky little beast....", "hh"=>"", "mm"=>"30"}, "commit"=>"Save", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"volunteer_records"}
```

Any clues on how to solve this will be much appreciated. The `protect_from_forgery` is set to `with: :exception`.

Comment: Well, the first thing is to get a repro. Without it, it's stabbing in the dark.

Comment: I have tried accessing the website from different browsers and different platforms. Can you suggest other ways I can try and reproduce? I can see in the logs that it worked for the users in other attempts.

Comment: I talked to one of the users and he said he had accessed the site after 8 hrs. So maybe I only get this after session expires. But I was not getting this earlier with Rails 3 and now it has been happening quite frequently. Any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: Quite frequently? Do your users leave browser open for days? Maybe there's another reason.

Comment: By quite frequently, i meant about 10 a day. I read some and Rails 3 had reset_session as the default action for protect_from_forgery (CSRF attacks). Rails 4 has with: :exception as default. If I switch it to reset_session, would there be any side effects I should know about?

Comment: I'm not aware of such side effects. Which doesn't mean there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
protect_from_forgery: :reset_session
```

worked for me. This was the default in Rails 3.

Comment: The reason this was changed was because it was possible that code would still be run even after the session was reset. Throwing an exception ensures that code processing will be halted. As long as there are no problems with that this is ok.